# Splash screen does not show in the first open(flutter)

Tags: flutter, splash-screen

I have implemented the native_splash_screen to my application, in android 12 the splash screen image does not show when the application opened for the first time in devices, If I open the application for the second or third time the image of splash screen shown.

Hopes help me with this problem.

**flutter_native_splash.yaml**

```
flutter_native_splash:
  color: "#ffffff"
 
  image: assets/images/logo_c.png
  android_12:
    image: assets/images/logo_c.png
  android: true
  #ios: false
  #web: false

  android_gravity: center
  fullscreen: true
```